# Character Rigging in Blender for Unreal Engine

Tags: rigging, import, unreal-engine

Can anyone help or direct me to definitive tutorials on proper rigging in Blender of imported FBX files, allowing the use of included character animations? Alternately, can an FBX be rigged inside Unreal?

When I set the FBX character import option to "None" for skeleton, the character's limbs are static during game play. When I set the FBX character import option to "UE4_Mannequin_Skeleton" for skeleton, the character and rig 'explode' in unpredictable ways.

The files can be downloaded here...

Distorted Unreal File: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mcprmjannl0lfqj/AAAY4IF4OkZwLO_bLtyrfsrIa?dl=0

Thank you in advance for your help! This is a game-stopper (pun intended).

-uenovice

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently playing with this too.

To get an idea of what you want to do, take the UE4 Mannequin's skeletal mesh and export it to FBX. File should be 853KB.

Import that in blender - on the blender import settings you want 'Z up' and 'Y forward', and on the Armatures tab you want 'Automatic Bone Orientation' ticked.

Then you have a clear look at what's going on with the UE4 mannequin (which has all those premade animations) - it has a root bone in the skeleton etc. From there you can work on changing the model to whatever you want and rerigging the existing armature. Then animation retargeting should work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "UE4 tools addon" made by Lluis Garcia, it is very helpful if you want to create animations for the standard UE4 skeleton :)